# Pandas Group By and Count

Tags: python, pandas, count, group-by, apply

A pandas dataframe df has 3 columns:

user_id,
session,
revenue

What I want to do now is group df by unique user_id and derive 2 new columns - one called number_sessions (counts the number of sessions associated with a particular user_id) and another called number_transactions (counts the number of rows under the revenue column that has a value > 0 for each user_id). How do I go about doing this?

I tried doing something like this:

```
df.groupby('user_id')['session', 'revenue'].agg({'number sessions': lambda x: len(x.session), 
'number_transactions': lambda x: len(x[x.revenue>0])})
```

Comment: There is no question or problem statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':['a','a','s','s','s'],
                   'session':[4,5,4,5,5],
                   'revenue':[-1,0,1,2,1]})

print (df)
   revenue  session user_id
0       -1        4       a
1        0        5       a
2        1        4       s
3        2        5       s
4        1        5       s

a = df.groupby('user_id') \
      .agg({'session': len, 'revenue': lambda x: len(x[x>0])}) \
      .rename(columns={'session':'number sessions','revenue':'number_transactions'})
print (a)
         number sessions  number_transactions
user_id                                      
a                      2                    0
s                      3                    3
```

---

```
a = df.groupby('user_id') \
      .agg({'session':{'number sessions': len}, 
            'revenue':{'number_transactions': lambda x: len(x[x>0])}}) 
a.columns = a.columns.droplevel()

print (a)
         number sessions  number_transactions
user_id                                      
a                      2                    0
s                      3                    3
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly the solution that I needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `nunique` for `session` to not double count the same session for a particular user

```
funcs = dict(session={'number sesssions': 'nunique'},
             revenue={'number transactions': lambda x: x.gt(0).sum()})
df.groupby('user_id').agg(funcs)
```

[image]

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':['a','a','s','s','s'],
                   'session':[4,5,4,5,5],
                   'revenue':[-1,0,1,2,1]})
```